# Not able to display ajax animated gif and text on JFrame

Tags: java, ajax, swing, progress-bar, animated-gif

I am writing a `Java` application which loads a file before performing any processing. I want to use an animated gif while the file is loading. I was able to create a `JFrame` which pops up as soon as the file loading starts and disappears just before the file is displayed in the GUI. Taking the help of these two answers, I was able to get this `JFrame` in place- 
[Load a gif image untill a method execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029647/load-a-gif-image-untill-a-method-execution?lq=1) and
[Creating a nice "LOADING..." animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634402/creating-a-nice-loading-animation?lq=1)

However, I am not able to display text or animated `gif` inside this `JFrame`. The `JFrame` is empty and shows nothing, but comes up and disappears on the desired time. Here is my code for the `showProgress()` and `hideProgress()` methods:

```
private JFrame loadingFrame = new JFrame("Notification");

private void showProgress() {
        //progress show code here
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon("ajax-loader.gif");
        loadingFrame.add(new JLabel("File loading in progress. Please wait... ", loading, JLabel.CENTER));
        loadingFrame.pack();
        loadingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loadingFrame.setSize(500, 200);
        loadingFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        loadingFrame.validate();
        loadingFrame.repaint();
        loadingFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

 private void hideProgress() {
        //progress show code here
        loadingFrame.setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
        loadingFrame.dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
    }
```

This is how the `JFrame` looks:
[image]

The .gif file is in the same folder as the .java file. Can someone point to where am I going wrong?

With reference to the answer provided here [Issue with gif animation in Java swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432480/issue-with-gif-animation-in-java-swing?rq=1), I made changes to my `showProgress()` method, which now calls a URL available on the internet. Here is the code:

```
 public void showProgress() throws Exception{
        //  imageURL = getClass().getResource("Processing.gif");
        //  loading = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
        ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IXqb.gif"));
       // loadingLabel = new JLabel("Please wait...");

        //JFrame
        loadingFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loadingFrame.setSize(400,300);
        loadingFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        loadingFrame.add(new JLabel(loading, JLabel.CENTER));
        loadingFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try using `ImageIcon loading = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ajax-loader.gif"));`

Comment: Gives a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Then the file is unlikely in the place you think it is. Is the java file compiled and added to a jar file or is the class file on the disk (in a directory)?  If it's in a jar, you need to inspect the jar (it's just a zip file) and ensure that both the class file and the image file are in the jar file and where you're expecting them to be.  If it's a class file, you need to do the same thing, but just check the directory

Comment: Yes the java file is complied. But, you are right, I cannot see the gif file in the target folder where all the class files are present. I placed the gif file in this folder, so now the class file and the gif are in the same folder. I ran the application again, but still the same issue. I am also not sure why I cannot see the JLabel.

Comment: *"The .gif file is in the same folder as the .java file."* A 'folder' is a GUI representation of a directory that is irrelevant to this question, which is all to do with directories or paths within a Zip file (e.g. a Jar file of the app.). Speaking of which: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Oh, and neither of those questions nor the accepted answer seems to mention the EDT, understanding of which is critical to getting a 'loading' animation to work. Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Yes. I understand your point on EDT and would try to implement it. However, for your suggestion related using a URL, I tried your using it, but still the jFrame displays nothing. I also tried your suggestion posted for this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432480/issue-with-gif-animation-in-java-swing?rq=1 I used exactly the same URL.

Comment: For sure now onwards @AndrewThompson

Comment: @AndrewThompson I pretty much understood the concept of Concurrency in Swing and also saw numerous examples for implementation. But still I am struggling to make it work for my GUI application. I am not sure how the doInBackground() process could return data for 3 different GUI components once the file is read.

Comment: The doInBackground() method should connect to R, use a Rscript to read the file, use another R script to extract some header information from the file, get back the values and then place them in three different components - As a JTree in a panel, the header information should go in JTextArea and the actual data from the file should be shown as a heat map in a separate panel. And, while this is being done in the background, a progress bar has to be displayed. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer May be you also have some inputs for my previous two comments. Thank you!

Comment: *"However, for your suggestion related using a URL,"* Either a deployed Jar file that includes the image, or to simply hot-link to one on the net, uses the same thing - an URL. In fact, we can even form a URL that points to a local file, but that's less useful ere. *"I tried your using it, but still the jFrame displays nothing."* Wait, you lost me there. Are you saying you tried it with the link to [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8IXqb.gif) that I used in the self contained code in that answer? If so, please edit the question to show the new code that tried to load that image.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added the new code. On a different note, since you suggested to using a different thread for the file reading process, I am trying to get this working and I am stuck (as mentioned in my previous two comments).

Comment: Here is where I have posted the SwingWorker issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956364/problems-in-using-swingworker-class-for-reading-a-file-and-implementing-a-jprogr

Comment: *"I have added the new code."* Sorry, thought it had already been mentioned, but I meant include a [mcve] of the new code. The answer that  hot-linked to an image was an **MCVE.** I.E. it has everything you need to see the problem (including imports and a `main` method).